# Extracting desired text from the string using regular expression using R

Tags: r, regex

I am reading the column of data.csv file and trying to extract desired text before the last forward slash from strings in column using regular expression. My column data looks like:

```
class:

org/apache/flume/api/virtual/loeadBalancing.java
org/apache/flume/file/Channel/testing/test2.java
org/apache/flume/recoverable/memory/test1.java
org/apache/flume/source/scribe/LogEntry.java
org/apache/flume/source/jms/TestJMSMessageConsumer.java
```

My desired output is:

```
org/apache/flume/ap/virtual
org/apache/flume/file/Channel/testing
org/apache/flume/recoverable/memory
org/apache/flume/source/scribe
org/apache/flume/source/jms/TestJMSMessageConsumer
```

So, basically, I am trying to extract sub string from class colum that excludes the text and backlash appearing after it. My current code is:

```
dfkg<- gsub( "\\.[^/]*$", "", data$class)
```

Can some one correct my regular string to generate the desired output?

Comment: Your statement  `extract desired text before the last forward slash from strings`, then why the last one is `rg/apache/flume/source/jms/TestJMSMessageConsumer`

Comment: `dirname(data$class)`

Comment: Sorry it was typo. Corrected now.

Comment: I meant `org/apache/flume/source/jms/TestJMSMessageConsumer.java` should be `org/apache/flume/source/jms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match the `/` followed by one or more characters that are not a `/` (`[^/]+`) until the end of the string (`$`) and replace it with blank (`""`).

```
sub("/[^/]+$", "", data$class)
#[1] "org/apache/flume/api/virtual"          "org/apache/flume/file/Channel/testing" "org/apache/flume/recoverable/memory"  
#[4] "org/apache/flume/source/scribe"        "org/apache/flume/source/jms"
```

---

In the OP's code

```
gsub( "\\.[^/]*$", "", data$class)
```

it is matching a dot (`\\.`) followed by zero or more characters that are not a `/` (`[^/]*`) until the end of the string (`$`).  So, basically it will first match the `.` at the `.java` followed by `java` which doesn't have any `/` and replace it with `""`.

---

Based on the comments by OP,

```
sub("\\.[^.]+\\.[^.]+$", "", 'org.apache.flume.api.virtualloeadBalancing.java' )
#[1] "org.apache.flume.api"
```

Comment: It works.  Can you explain me the problem in my code?

Comment: Yes. It does work now.

Comment: Can you explain the trouble in my code. Just another correction is required, after getting this, how  can I replace backslash with "." dot ?

Comment: @Analyzer Did you meant to have `"org.apache.flume.api.virtual"`  In that case `gsub("[/]", ".",  sub("\\/[^/]+$", "", data$class))`

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly fine. However, I need to check my regular expression and understand the difference between sub and gsub. Sub is probably used to substring the text while gsub is more specific for replacing the text.

Comment: @Analyzer I updated the post about the problem in your code.  `gsub` is for global substitution.  It will be do the substitution more than one time and `sub` does it a single time.  The intial problem can be solved with `sub` as this requires only a single instance of replacement

Comment: my corde works fine to extract every thing before the last '. ' appearing in the text like  ' org.apache.flume.api.virtualloeadBalancing.java '  when executed with ' gsub( "\\.[^/]*$", "", data$class) '. Isnt it ?

Comment: @Analyzer It wil extract the `org/apache/flume/api/virtual/loeadBalancing` in your original `org/apache/flume/api/virtual/loeadBalancing.java`

Comment: I agree, but I am talking when my text is in the format  'org.apache.flume.api.virtualloeadBalancing.java ' that it should be able to extract 'org.apache.flume.api' , right?

Comment: @Analyzer It will match the `.` at the first instance i.e. org. and all other charactesr in `[^/]*$`, so you will get `org`.  I am not sure why you are using the `/` as it not in the new string

Comment: @Analyzer if you need the substring you wanted, `sub("\\.[^.]+\\.[^.]+$", "", 'org.apache.flume.api.virtualloeadBalancing.java ' )
#[1] "org.apache.flume.api"`